# How do I sum the product of two values, across multiple objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Imagine I have a portfolio `p` that has 2 stocks `port_stocks`. What I want to do is run a calculation on each `port_stock`, and then sum up all the results.

```
[60] pry(main)> p.port_stocks
=> [#<PortStock:0x00007fd520e064e0
  id: 17,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 385,
  volume: 2000,
  purchase_price: 5.9,
  total_spend: 11800.0>,
 #<PortStock:0x00007fd52045be68
  id: 18,
  portfolio_id: 1,
  stock_id: 348,
  volume: 1000,
  purchase_price: 9.0,
  total_spend: 9000.0>]
[61] pry(main)>
```

So, in essence, using the code above I would like to do this:

```
ps = p.port_stocks.first #(`id=17`)
first = ps.volume * ps.purchase_price # 2000 * 5.9 = 11,800

ps = p.port_stocks.second #(`id=18`)
second = ps.volume * ps.purchase_price # 1000 * 9.0 = 9,000

first + second = 19,800
```

I want to simply get `19,800`. Ideally I would like to do this in a very Ruby way.

If I were simply summing up all the values in 1 `total_spend`, I know I could simply do: `p.port_stocks.map(&:total_spend).sum` and that would be that.

But not sure how to do something similar when I am first doing a math operation on each object, then adding up all the products from all the objects. This should obviously work for 2 objects or 500.

Comment: Try: `p.port_stocks.map{|ps| ps.volume * ps.purchase_price}.sum`

Comment: Do you want to do the calculation in Ruby or in your database?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you shouldn't use floats for monetary values.

Comment: @Stefan I want to do the calculation in Ruby. Also, why should I use floats for monetary values? I feel like I have heard that somewhere before, but can you give me a link or something I can read up more about that and explore the alternatives please? Thanks!

Comment: @guitarman Perfect. That works like a charm. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @marcamillion _"why should I use floats"_ – you should **not** use floats for monetary values. Because floats are inaccurate and can easily introduce rounding errors, e.g. `0.1 * 0.2` returns `0.020000000000000004`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/477037 for a detailed explanation. Take a look a the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem and its [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) integration.

Comment: @Stefan - didn't know that, thanks for raising it and the explanation. Reading the linked post now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way of doing this using Rails is to pass a block to `sum`, such as the following:

```
p.port_stocks.sum do |port_stock|
  port_stock.volume * port_stock.purchase_price
end
```

That uses the method dedicated to totalling figures, and tends to be very fast and efficient - particularly when compared to manipulating the data ahead of calling a straight `sum` without a block.

A quick benchmark [here](https://repl.it/@SDRACK/QuickBenchmark) typically shows it performing ~20% faster than the obvious alternatives.

I've not been able to test, but give that a try and it should resolve this for you.

Let me know how you get on!

---

Just a quick update as you also mention the best Ruby way, `sum` was [introduced in 2.4](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/02/ruby-2-4-introduces-enumerable-sum.html), though on older versions of Ruby you can use [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (also aliased to `inject`):

```
p.port_stocks.reduce(0) do |sum, port_stock|
  sum + (port_stock.volume * port_stock.purchase_price)
end
```

This isn't as efficient as `sum`, but thought I'd give you the options :)

Comment: The assignment in the latter example is superfluous, i.e. just use `+` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to use [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to iterate through all stocks, but instead to sum all total_spend values, you could calculate it for each stock. After, you sum all results and your done:

```
p.port_stocks.map{|ps| ps.volume * ps.purchase_price}.sum
```

Or you could use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) like SRack did. This would return the result with one step/iteration.

Comment: `collection.map { ... }.sum` => `collection.sum { ... }`

Comment: Performs worse than using `sum` with a block, and is less readable IMHO.

Comment: @SRack there proof to suggest that it performs worse?

Comment: I've benchmarked it in the past @maramillion ([code here](https://repl.it/@SDRACK/QuickBenchmark) if you're interested), after answering a question similar to this with Guitarman's solution and seeing someone else post to use `sum` :) Was interested to see how `map`, `reduce` and `sum` compared, so I ran the numbers. `sum` generally comes out on top (usually by ~20%), and I'd maintain it's the most readable.